# Automatically apply labels to github pull requests

Tags: github

I'm trying to find some resources on how to add a label automatically when creating a new pull request. So far, I haven't found any documentation on this. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

It really depends what and when you want to label those pull requests with. Since there is no rule engine directly on GitHub for this to auto-label issues or pull requests you have 2 options:

1. Find something on the [GitHub Marketplace tagged with `label`](https://github.com/marketplace?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=label). If nothing suits you'll have to go for option 2.
2. Write your own script, GitHub Application or GitHub Action that interfaces with the GitHub API to set those labels based on your specific requirements.